# MPMusicPlayerController kills RemoteIO on iPhone Speaker route

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

I have an application that uses RemoteIO for input-output processing (PlayAndRecord category) and also includes an MPMusicPlayerController.

The weird thing:   On iPhone only, when RemoteIO is running and the iPhone Speaker is the audio destination, starting playback in the MPMusicPlayerController will result in a  kAudioSessionBeginInterruption  event and my RemoteIO is shutdown.   The iPod music (MPMusicPlayerController) continues to play.

It seems that on iPhone, with the Speaker route, RemoteIO and MPMusicPlayerController cannot both play?    On iPad I have had no problem running both RemoteIO and MPMusicPlayerController.  On iPhone, if I plug something (headphones, speakers, etc) into the headset jack, everything works just fine as well and both streams will run.    It seems to only be an issue on iPhone, if Speaker is the destination.

I override the AudioSession output to the iPhone speaker (kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryDefaultToSpeaker) when Receiver output is detected, this is done to be a more natural expectation for the user.   The iPod player seems to also do this.

I also set the property kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers  to true.   This allows the iPod player to (presumably) play along.

I wrote some test code to restart my RemoteIO session later, and that will in turn cause the MPMusicPlayerController to stop playing.   Thus indicating that the speaker destination may be exclusive?

I've also tried with both the 'iPodMusicPlayer' and 'applicationMusicPlayer' members of MPMusicPlayerController, there were no differences in the above results between the two.

Any advice certainly appreciated

Comment: After further testing and finding this the iPhone Speaker destination to be the only odd case (iPad works fine, headsets work fine), I have filed a Bug with Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go ahead and answer my own question, since I think I've figured it out.  Still, I am not happy with the results.

It appears that the MPMusicPlayerController (iPod Player) is changing the Audio Route, regardless of whatever route the application that is already using for it's RemoteIO.   As it turns out, this happens on both iPhone and iPad.

This can be easily demonstrated by:

- PlugIn USB Audio Input Device
- Connect BlueTooth Speakers
- Set System iPod Player to use BlueTooth Speakers
- Launch App that does PlayRecord using RemoteIO with embedded MPMusicPlayerController
- Audio I/O (PlayRecord) will process from USB Input to Receiver output
- Engage Play on embedded MPMusicPlayerController

Result:

- Audio route will change to BlueTooth Input/Output
- Song will play on BlueTooth speakers
- RemoteIO will receive kAudioSessionBeginInterruption
- Restarting RemoteIO stream will result in MPMusicPlayerController being stopped

What I wish would happen:

- MPMusicPlayerController will simply play to whatever audio destination is already in use by the application.

I have appended my Apple Bug with the above information.